# How can I customise the browser's output for print/print preview?

Tags: css, browser, printing

I'm trying to dynamically hide certain DIV's when a print (or print preview) occurs from the browser.

I can easily differentiate statically by having two style sheets, one for normal and one for print media:

But I need to go one step further and hide some elements dynamically when the print style sheet becomes active during a print based upon certain criteria

One way to easily solve it would be to handle a DOM event for handling print / printview, then I could just use jQuery to change the display:none on the classes that need to be hidden, but I can't find a DOM print event!!

Anyone know what the solution is?

Comment: You mean you need to hide divs on the screen after the user prints (or print previews) the page?

Answer (score 5):

Not all browsers allow you to capture the print event. I've seen this tackled by adding a 'print this page' link and then using that click event to accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you need a print event. All you need to do is adjust your `@media print` styles based on your Javascript(?) criteria. When the user attempts to print the page, the `@media print` style will apply and your styles will be in effect:

```
<html>
<head>
<style id="styles" type="text/css">
@media print { .noprint { display:none; } }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = Math.random();

if (x > .5) {
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = '@media print { .maybe_noprint { display:none; } }';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="noprint">This will never print.</div>
<span class="maybe_noprint">This may print depending on the value of x.</span>
</body>
</html>
```

If you are using server-side criteria to determine what prints, then just have server-side code spit out `@media print` to decorate the classes as necessary. Also, you may want to consider modifying an existing class that's already inside `@media print`, or building up the new CSS using something other than `innerHTML`, which I'll admit smells awful to me, but seems to work in Opera 9.6, Safari for Windows 3.1.2, IE 6 and Firefox 2.0.0.17 (I didn't test any other browsers).

Answer (score 4):

Just tag those DIVs with a class that's hidden on the print stylesheet:

**HTML**

```
<div id='div19' class='noprint'>
  ...
</div>
```

**print.css**

```
.noprint {
  display: none;
}
```

If you don't know in advance which elements you need to hide, you can use javascript to set the class for the given objects:

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('div19').className='noprint';
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an [onbeforeprint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536906(VS.85).aspx) event in IE. It doesn't appear to be supported by other major browsers. (I tested Firefox 3.0.3 and Safari 3.1.2.)